# Huggingface Instructor Embeddings using URL or Service

Tags: python, airflow, huggingface-transformers, information-retrieval, langchain

Currently I use Astro Airflow to insert document into database vector. The problem is when I want to call instructor-xl, it's always error:

```
Downloading (…)7f436/tokenizer.json: 100%|##########| 2.42M/2.42M [00:00<00:00, 3.82MB/s]
[2023-08-09, 02:30:12 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:149} WARNING - 
Downloading (…)okenizer_config.json:   0%|          | 0.00/2.40k [00:00<?, ?B/s]
[2023-08-09, 02:30:12 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:149} WARNING - 
Downloading (…)okenizer_config.json: 100%|##########| 2.40k/2.40k [00:00<00:00, 7.34MB/s]
[2023-08-09, 02:30:13 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:149} WARNING - 
Downloading (…)f57f436/modules.json:   0%|          | 0.00/461 [00:00<?, ?B/s]
[2023-08-09, 02:30:13 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:149} WARNING - 
Downloading (…)f57f436/modules.json: 100%|##########| 461/461 [00:00<00:00, 1.71MB/s]
[2023-08-09, 02:30:13 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:149} INFO - load INSTRUCTOR_Transformer
[2023-08-09, 02:30:27 UTC] {local_task_job_runner.py:225} INFO - Task exited with return code Negsignal.SIGKILL
[2023-08-09, 02:30:28 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2653} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

I want to solve this by make instructor-xl as service using compute engine. but I'm not sure how to use/call the embedding.

this is example when I make LLM as service and I can call it using langchain.llms.HuggingFaceTextGenInference

```
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.llms import HuggingFaceTextGenInference
retriever = db.as_retriever()
llm = HuggingFaceTextGenInference(
                                inference_server_url="http://localhost:8081/",
                                max_new_tokens=1024,
                                top_k = 5,
                                top_p = 0.8,
                                typical_p = 0.95,
                                temperature = 0.5,
                                repetition_penalty = 1
                                )
qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=llm, chain_type="stuff", retriever=retriever)
```

I can't find the same method for embedding in langchain

Answer (score 0):

The problem with airflow task is because instructor-xl has large size. it solved when I change to instructor-large